# Variable name suggestions for representing both remote URL and local file path

Tags: variables, naming-conventions, naming

I need to store string value which can be a remote URL or local file path. What would be the best name for this? I thought of using 'URI' but I'm not sure if the relative file path can be called URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For absolute file paths you can use the file URI scheme `file:/myPath`. In this case you can therefor use the name URI. However, there is no URI scheme for relative paths so if you really need to store relative paths you could use the name *location* to refer to either a URL or a (possibly relative) file path.

See also [The "file" URI Scheme](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8089).

Answer (score 0):

You can name it (snake-case):

```
uri_or_path
```

Or (Camel-case):

```
uriOrPath
```